# Missing "cpan>" prompt when running the CPAN shell in a Strawberry Perl environment under Cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan, strawberry-perl

I've encountered a strange prompt problem when running the CPAN shell in a Strawberry Perl environment under Cygwin.

When launching the CPAN using `perl -MCPAN -eshell` I get the following output:

```
cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9600)
Enter 'h' for help.
```

Please not that the standard `cpan>` prompt is missing. Why is that and how do I fix it?

When typing `quit\n` I get the prompt but **after** I issue the command:

```
quit
cpan> Lockfile removed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic problem running interactive windows programs in a cygwin terminal window.
I don't have a handy cygwin installation to try it on, but try either

```
cygstart perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

or install [conin](http://groups.google.com/group/mintty-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1f9cf480117b8a0b) and do

```
conin perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

Answer (score 0):

If running git-bash (not cygwin), then start cpan with winpty:

```
winpty perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

The 'cpan> ' prompt should now be presented.  You may get a warning:

```
Unable to get Terminal Size. The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo call didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work. at C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 410.
```

Which can be resolved by exporting the COLUMNS and LINES variables with the appropriate values.  (Say):

```
export COLUMNS=80
export LINES=100
```

There are scripts that will pull the current window settings using bash, node or python.

bash:

```
export LINES=$(tput lines)
export COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
```